# Extract Value from Insert Script

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I have a Insert script where i am trying to extract value

Here is the script

```
    @scriptprod=INSERT  intoProducts_Details
        ( VAL_ID ,
          ProductID ,
          SONumber ,
          ProductTypeName ,
          QuantitySold ,
          Hours ,
          Comments ,
          Synch_Status ,
          ProdID
        )
VALUES  ( 'V420131010213137TEST' ,
          '186' ,
          '5000000010' ,
          'Bundled Anesthesia' ,
          '9' ,
          '12.00' ,
          'test anas' ,
          '' ,
          'PD20131011121909999000'
        )
```

i tried using like

```
substring(
@scriptprod,
charindex('PD20',@scriptprod,0),
LEN(@scriptprod)-CHARINDEX('PD20',@scriptprod,0)-1)
```

which i am not getting please help

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting your question correctly then you want to return a value after Insert. I think you are looking for something like this :-

```
  OUTPUT Inserted.ID
```

ie,

```
Insert intoProducts_Details (VAL_ID,ProductID,SONumber,ProductTypeName,QuantitySold,Hours,Comments,Synch_Status,ProdID) 
OUTPUT Inserted.ID
Values ('V420131010213137TEST','186','5000000010','Bundled Anesthesia','9','12.00','test anas','','PD20131011121909999000')
```

You may also check **[SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)**

> Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in
>   the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger,
>   function, or batch. Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if
>   they are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch.

You may try this using `SCOPE_IDENTITY`

```
Insert intoProducts_Details (VAL_ID,ProductID,SONumber,ProductTypeName,QuantitySold,Hours,Comments,Synch_Status,ProdID) 
    OUTPUT Inserted.ID
    Values ('V420131010213137TEST','186','5000000010','Bundled Anesthesia','9','12.00','test anas','','PD20131011121909999000')

@scriptprod = SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

**EDIT:-**

If you want to get some value from the database then you may use the simple `select` command for that.

```
select * from table where id = 186;
```

or else if you want to get the value before the insert operation is done then you have to consider your whole value as varchar and then search for your string which you want!

Comment: NO i need to get the value from the insert query,for example from the above menstioned query i need to get "186" which is ProductID value

Comment: Rahul i understood your point see i am sending thousands of insert script  in sql server from my .net application. i need to capture those Product id values from insert script which i pass from my application.the query which i menstion is one example. from that query i need to extract just product id.hope you understood my point